# Need a java library for dynamic PDF creation

Tags: java, pdf

I just got some requirements from a group of users that need dynamic PDF's created. Our software stack uses spring-boot java backend and a vueJS front end.

Requirements :

1. barcode support
2. dynamic fonts, styles etc..
3. support for images
4. multiple page print outs

I would prefer to use some sort of GUI or easy-to-use user interface to create these PDF files. I would like to drag and drop elements into the software and generate a report. I'd like to pass parameters into this report that can be dynamic. This data will likely come from our databases.

I have researched and tried implementing iText and Jasper Reports. iText mostly uses HTML and CSS, but for complex reports this can become a tedious and long process.

We have yet to figure out how to implement Jasper Reports into our current technology stack successfully. Java 8/Spring Boot/VueJS

I'm looking for a modern library that makes it very easy to dynamically generate PDF reports. We will likely pull data from a database and populate the report with this data. The only thing that will be static in these reports is a company logo. Barcodes and data will all be dynamic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://zetcode.com/java/pdfbox/ is something I was looking at recently on the same quest, although more of a "fill out a template and deliver it" type than full on generation.

Build your bar code, qr code, whatever using other libraries and simply add them as a image to the file.

Might even consider keeping